# Не корректное обновление ListView adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, adapter, eventbus

```
//Все лишнее из кода выбросил, оставляю суть
public class MainActivityLink extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    MyCommandProcessing myCommandProcessing;
    MyAdapterLink  adapter;
    ArrayList<MyArrayLink> items = new ArrayList<MyArrayLink>();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myCommandProcessing = new MyCommandProcessing();

        items = myCommandProcessing.getAllLinkOnIDGroup(idGroup, items);
        adapter = new MyAdapterLink(this, items);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLink);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);  //Вывод данных проходит как надо
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
        myCommandProcessing.getAllLinkOnIDGroup(idGroup, items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //проблема с обновлением ListView
    }
}

public class MyCommandProcessing {
ArrayList<MyArrayLink> getAllLinkOnIDGroup(long idGroup, ArrayList<MyArrayLink> items){
        items.clear();
        List<DBLink> allDBLink = new DBLink().getLinkOnIDGroup(idGroup);
        for(int i=0; i<allDBLink.size();i++) {
            items.add(items.size(), new MyArrayLink(allDBLink.get(i).getId(), allDBLink.get(i).name,  allDBLink.get(i).id_group, allDBLink.get(i).link, allDBLink.get(i).countNew, allDBLink.get(i).countAll,
                    allDBLink.get(i).year, allDBLink.get(i).month, allDBLink.get(i).day, allDBLink.get(i).hh, allDBLink.get(i).mm, allDBLink.get(i).ss));
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что после выполнения метода `onEvent(MessageEvent event)`
данные в `ListView` не обновляются, обновление происходит только в том случае (!), если прикоснуться к элементу `ListView` (!). т.е. интуитивно я понимаю, что `onEvent(MessageEvent event)` вызывается средствами `EventBus` и это происходит в другом потоке не связанном с интерфейсом. Как решить такую проблему?

Буду благодарен любым ответам.

Comment: А если обернуть обновление адаптера в runOnUiThread()?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ЮрийСПб! Вы правы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если метод вызывается не в основном потоке и из него надо что-то в основном сделать, то в активити есть спец. метод для этого:

```
runOnUiThread()
```

внутри него создаётся объект Runnable и в его методе `run` код будет выполнен в основном потоке, т.е. в том, где можно взаимодействовать с UI